# mysql Select Query in two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, json, select

How do i query from two different tables in sql with one php script and parse it into one json object? Thank you!

here is my php

```
<?php  



$sql = "select * from schedule;"; 
 $sql1 = "select * from matches;"; 
 $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);


 $response = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
array_push($response, array("n_name"=>$row[1],"start"=>$row[4],"end"=>$row[5],"venue"=>$row[6]));
 }

 $data = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
array_push($data, array("teamone"=>$row[1]));
 }

echo json_encode (array("schedule_response"=>$response, $data));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is the output

```
{"schedule_response":
    [{
        "n_name":null,
        "start":"2016-11-09 00:00:00",
        "end":"2016-11-16 00:00:00",
        "venue":"aaaaaa"
     }],
    "0":[{"teamone":"aaa"}]}
```

What i want is something like this

```
{"schedule_response":
    [{
        "n_name":null,
        "start":"2016-11-09 00:00:00",
        "end":"2016-11-16 00:00:00",
        "venue":"aaaaaa",
        "teamone":"aaa"
    }]
}
```

Comment: How should the expected output be? Can you give us an example?

Comment: posted a photo sir. Thanks

Comment: SQL Join could do the trick..

Comment: Add the expected output as text in your question, not as an image.

Comment: How are the two tables related to each other? Why is there only one team in `matches`?